# UI Thread Exception on Extended Grid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading, mvvm

I have searched for this already and none of the answers seem to help. I am getting this error when trying to fill a datagrid

> An ItemsControl is inconsistent with its items source.
>
> This exception was thrown because the generator for control 'ExtendedGrid.ExtendedGridControl.ExtendedDataGrid Items.Count:9' with name '(unnamed)' has received sequence of CollectionChanged events that do not agree with the current state of the Items collection.  The following differences were detected:
>     Accumulated count 8 is different from actual count 9.  [Accumulated count is (Count at last Reset + #Adds - #Removes since last Reset).]

I can get it to work 80%~ of the time using thread.sleep but when it goes out to other machines the chances are that it will not work even for that 80%.

I am filling this list with a background worker, that list is then bound to a data grid using the ExtendedGrid.dll. The code for the background worker is:

```
Private Sub SalesHistoryBackgroundWorker_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles Me.DoWork

    Dim ss As New OperaDAL.hsanalSelects(_DBPath)

    Dim l As List(Of hsanal)
    If _cstwh Is Nothing Then
        l = ss.GethsanalByAccount(_SN_Account, True)
    Else
        l = ss.GethsanalByProduct(_cstwh.cs_ref, True)
    End If


    l.Reverse()


    For Each i In l

        If Not Me.CancellationPending Then
            _History.Add(i)
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next



    If Not Me.CancellationPending Then

        While l.Count > 0
            Dim theS = l(0)

            If theS.sa_product.Trim <> "" Then

                Dim toOut = (From a In l.AsParallel Where theS.sa_product = a.sa_product Select a).ToList 

                If toOut.Count > 0 Then
                    Dim SumQty = (From a In toOut Select a.sa_qty).Sum
                    Dim SumValue = (From a In toOut Select a.sa_trvalue).Sum


                    If Not Me.CancellationPending Then

                        _HistoryView.Add(New GroupHSAnal(toOut.First.sa_product, toOut.First.cn_desc, SumQty, SumValue))


                        Do While toOut.Count > 0
                            Dim item = toOut(0)
                            l.Remove(item)
                            toOut.RemoveAt(0)
                        Loop

                    Else
                        l.Clear() 
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                Dim toOut = (From a In l.AsParallel Where a.sa_product.Trim = "" And a.sa_desc.Trim.ToUpper = theS.sa_desc.Trim.ToUpper Select a).ToList 
                If toOut.Count > 0 Then

                    Dim SumQty = (From a In toOut Select a.sa_qty).Sum
                    Dim SumValue = (From a In toOut Select a.sa_trvalue).Sum

                    If Not Me.CancellationPending Then
                        Thread.Sleep(6)

                        _HistoryView.Add(New GroupHSAnal("", toOut.First.sa_desc, SumQty, SumValue))


                        Do While toOut.Count > 0
                            Dim item = toOut(0)
                            l.Remove(item)
                            toOut.RemoveAt(0)
                        Loop

                    Else
                        l.Clear()
                    End If

                End If

            End If

        End While

    End If

    _CanceledOk = True
End Sub
```

If anyone knows of a solution that would be a great help.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved had to set the target framework which was on .net 4.0 to 4.5. Then I was able to use the EnableCollectionSynchronization method which wasn't available in 4.0 and that has now fixed this error.